# Как опубликовать статью в Telegraph с помощью Python?

Tags: python

Всем привет! Нужно опубликовать статью в сервисе Telegra.ph с помощью Python. Пытался сделать это с помощью модулей "telegraph" и "python-telegraphapi", но безуспешно. Пытался просто запустить код, который приложен к инструкции к модулю "telegraph", как образец:

```
from telegraph import Telegraph
telegraph = Telegraph()
telegraph.create_account(short_name='1337')
response = telegraph.create_page(
    'Hey',
    html_content='<p>Hello, world!</p>'
)
print('http://telegra.ph/{}'.format(response['path']))
```

Выдаёт эту ошибку:

```
File "AutoContent.py", line 6, in <module>
    html_content='<p>Hello, world!</p>'
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telegraph\api.py", line 168, in create_page
    'return_content': return_content
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telegraph\api.py", line 40, in method
    raise TelegraphException(response.get('error'))
telegraph.exceptions.TelegraphException: PAGE_SAVE_FAILED
```

Пробовал образец кода модуля "python-telegraphapi":

```
from telegraphapi import Telegraph
telegraph = Telegraph()
telegraph.createAccount("PythonTelegraphAPI")
page = telegraph.createPage("Hello world!", html_content="<b>Welcome, TelegraphAPI!</b>")
print('http://telegra.ph/{}'.format(page['path']))
```

Выходит эта ошибка:

```
File "AutoContent.py", line 4, in <module>
    page = telegraph.createPage("Hello world!", html_content="<b>Welcome, TelegraphAPI!</b>")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telegraphapi\main.py", line 139, in createPage
    "return_content": return_content
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telegraphapi\main.py", line 32, in make_method
    post_request.json()['error'])
telegraphapi.exceptions.TelegraphAPIException: Error while executing createPage: PAGE_SAVE_FAILED
```

Даже не знаю, куда смотреть, чтобы решить проблему. Пожалуйста, помогите!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример с [`telegraph` модулем](https://github.com/python273/telegraph) работает как есть. Легко напрямую воспользоваться [Telegraph API](http://telegra.ph/api). Чтобы создать новую страницу нужен `access_token`, чтобы получить `access_token`, можно отправить createAccount запрос:

```
# get :access-token
POST https://api.telegra.ph/createAccount?short_name=не важно
```

Подставив из ответа сервера значение `access_token`, можно опубликовать новую статью на https://telegra.ph:

```
# create page
:access-token = b968da509bb76866c35425099bc0989a5ec3b32997d55286c657e6994bbb

POST https://api.telegra.ph/createPage

access_token=:access-token&title=Sample Page&content=[{"tag":"p","children":["Hello, world!"]}]&return_content=true
```

<sup>запросы используют [emacs' restclient](http://emacsrocks.com/e15.html) синтаксис</sup>

На Питоне это может выглядеть как:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def make_request(method, **params):
    url = 'https://api.telegra.ph/' + method
    params = {k: v if isinstance(v, str) else json.dumps(v) for k, v in params.items()}
    r = json.loads(urlopen(url + '?' + urlencode(params)).read())
    if not r['ok']:
        raise ValueError(str(r))
    return r['result']
    

def get_access_token(short_name):
    return make_request('createAccount',
        short_name=short_name)['access_token']
        
def create_page(**params):
    return make_request('createPage', **params)
    
# try your own input    
from browser import document, html
@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    token = get_access_token(document["short_name"].value)
    title = document["title"].value
    page = create_page(access_token=token,
                       title=title,
                       content=document["content"].value)
    print(page['url'])
    document <= html.P(html.A(title, href=page['url']))
</script>
<div><label for="short_name">Имя: <input id="short_name" value="SO client"></div>
<div><label for="title">Заголовок: <input id="title" value="Привет"></div>
<div><label for="content">Элементы статьи: <textarea id="content" cols=30>[{"tag": "p", "children": ["Здравствуй Мир!"]}]</textarea></div>
<div><button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></div>
```

Comment: Очень благодарен за код! Но не могу понять, в каком виде нужно писать текст, который нужно опубликовать, т.е. не могу понять вот это: [{"tag": "p", "children": ["Здравствуй Мир!"]}]. Не могли бы вы это объяснить? И ещё не могу понять параметр short_name, со значением SO client в вашем примере. Зачем он нужен?

Comment: @hohokibeza код показан, чтобы картину "как это устроено" показать. Фактически, используйте более дружественные обёртки типа tetelgraph модуля. К примеру, вы можете содержимое как html передать (telegraph модуль за вас превратит во ввод ожидаемый api.telegra.ph сервисом) См. код в вопросе¶ Если не знаете что такое short_name, то оно вам не нужно (любое значение подставьте).

Comment: но код с вопроса выдаёт ошибку. Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы показать работающий код публикации статьи на Telegraph и выводом ссылки на эту статью с помощью модуля telegraph? Был бы вам очень благодарен!

Comment: @hohokibeza: слова в ответе *"работает как есть"* -- означают, что я скопировал код как есть, запустил и он успешно завершился¶ Аналог этого кода прямо в ответе приведён, который можно запустить прямо в браузере, нажав "Выполнить код" кнопку. Если этот код запускать слишком много раз с одними и теме же параметрами, то он может ошибку вернуть. Решение простое: меняйте параметры и не запускайте слишком часто.

Comment: ваш код у меня работает, а вот с модуля telegraph - нет. Раньше выдавало `telegraph.exceptions.TelegraphException: PAGE_SAVE_FAILED` (в вопросе писал), сейчас же запускаю - вообще выдаёт `ImportError: cannot import name 'Telegraph'`, хотя модуль telegraph установлен. Не знаете в чём причина обеих ошибок? Запускаю код-пример [отсюда](https://github.com/python273/telegraph), никак его не изменяю.

Comment: @hohokibeza о ImportError следует отдельный вопрос задать. Создайте *минимальный* пример кода, который ошибку вызывает и опубликуйте как новый вопрос (с полным traceback). Добавьте вывод `pip show telegraph` команды и `python -c 'import telegraph; print(telegraph)'`